# Historical IP reputation data

Tags: firewalls, logging, log-analysis

I have a firewall log with events from 2 years ago. I want to examine that log as if I was investigating at the time of collection (2 years ago).

However, I would like to use IP address reputation data. But I was not yet able to find a source that provides historical IP address reputation data.

What are your ideas/sources to deal with that situation?

Answer (score 1):

IPs get changed and reassigned all the time. Any automatically collected reputation data gets stale fast. It's unlikely sites will archive that info.

But, I have been in the same situation. What I ended up doing was using my Google Fu and the Wayback Machine to search during that timeframe to see if forums, reputation sites, etc. mentioned the IPs in question and I was able to find enough information to help an investigation.

But there will be no guarantees that you will have similar success.

Comment: thanks. Thats a good advice, if no other answer fits ;) Maybe I am  ignorant, but delta lists shouldnt be that big, I guess...

Comment: You might be surprised. The other problem is that innocent users of current IPs will be tainted with the historical reputation. It's already a problem with domain blacklists. There might be some sources that store that info, but requests for services\sites is off-topic here.